# HSM : Storage of Normal user PIN or pass phrase for an unattended start

Tags: pkcs#11, hsm, passphrase

We are using Ncipher/Thales HSM to store keys.
The Operator card used for this is protected via passphrase.
We are using PKCS11Interop to communicate with the HSM and the PIN  needs to be provided to communicate with HSM.
What is the industry practice to store such security pins / pass phrases for an unattended process?
We need to install our application in multiple boxes , how do we maintain security of the pin.

Answer (score 0):

We used two different practices to store PIN data and becoming attended or unattended is not different. You have to store PIN Data in protected environment, SQL Server or [MainFrame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_mainframe) systems that access is safeguarded and highly controlled.

Not only environments but data format is important, you can not store clear PIN data but in encrypted forms. You have to use HSM for encryption-decryption too.

1. Store PIN Data encrypted under LMK form.

   First encrypt clear PIN data with "Encrypt a Clear PIN" command(BA) and store output data. To verify PIN , you have to call "Decrypt an Encrypted PIN" command(NG). If you want to use those commands you have to enable "Clear PIN" commands in Thales HSM so its is highly vulnerable to insider attacks. If an insider who have access to PIN data and HSM, can easily get PIN values.
2. [Offset Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identification_number#IBM_3624_.2B_offset_method).

   You do not store sensitive information that can be used to generate clear PIN but data that can be used for verification purposes only. You store **Offset**, **Decimalisation Table**, **PIN Validation Data** for verification of data that comes from customer(PIN is sent to central servers under ZPK or TPK encrypted from ATM). You can not generate customer PIN from those data so it is more secure. You can use PIN Verification Commands(DA,EA)